# Fixed container, enumerable, intellisense indexable (or member)

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make an object to hold some strings. The object can be anything, including collections, arrays ... The strings need to be **enumerable** (IEnumerable or similar). Each string indexer needs to be known by **intellisense** and **Reflection is a last option**. One single object, no separate object for indexers.

**Example usage:**

```
public static class features
{
    public const string favorite = "blue background";
    public const string nice = "animation";
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (string feature in features)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(feature);
        }
        //... select a feature
        Console.WriteLine(features.favorite);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I will use the first solution proposed by Jim Mischel, modified to use reflection, as that gets the advantages I'm interested in at the current time.

- encapsulates everything in one entity
- names are directly associated    with values
- enumerator is dynamic

  ```
  public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
  {
      FieldInfo[] strings = this.GetType().GetFields();
      foreach (FieldInfo currentField in strings)
      {
          yield return currentField.GetValue(null).ToString();
      }
      yield break;
  }
  ```

I thank everyone for your effort.

Comment: You`re doing it so wrong...

Comment: So here's your opportunity to do it better.

Comment: Right. `ExpandoObject` would work, but you want the type to be known by Intellisense...

Comment: The object is known at compile time, and constant.

Comment: Use a dictionary of an enumerable to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offhand, I can think of two ways to do it. However, since it must be `IEnumerable<string>` it can't be a static class because static classes can't implement interfaces. Nor can static methods implement interface methods.

The first way uses constants and an enumerator that just returns them in order:

```
public class Features: IEnumerable<string>
{
    public const string Favorite = "blue background";
    public const string Nice = "animation";


    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Favorite;
        yield return Nice;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The second way stores the values in an array and uses an `enum` for the indexes. The enumerator just returns the enumerator for the array. Again, this is not static because of the enumerator, and also because indexers can't be static.

```
public enum FeaturesIndex
{
    Favorite = 0,
    Nice = 1
}

public class Features2 : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private static readonly string[] _features = new string[]
        {
            "blue background",
            "animation"
        };

    public string this [FeaturesIndex ix]
    {
        get { return _features[(int) ix]; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<string>) _features).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

A third possibility, as pointed out by others, is using a dictionary and either an enumeration or defined constants as keys. It's an interesting approach, the only potential drawback being that you can't guarantee the order in which keys will be returned when you enumerate the collection. If that's a problem, you could have your enumerator sort the sequence before returning.

Any way you look at it, there are tradeoffs. Both of my solutions require manual synchronization of keys and values. In the first, you have to make sure that the enumerator retures all of the values. In the second, you have to ensure that your `enum` matches the array.

Pick your poison.

It also depends on how you're going to use the thing. My first solution has the benefit of simplicity and would probably be quite acceptable if it's a write-once, use-forever kind of thing. The second option has the benefit of using an indexer, which is more commonly associated with collections.

Comment: The dilemma based on my biased consideration is 1)first example 
+encapsulates everything in one entity
+names are directly associated with values, however
-enumerator is not dynamic, each indexer is "hard coded" and we are prone to forget/mistakes
2) second example
+enumerator is dynamic, but
-names are separated from value, prone to human error
-separate entity for indexer

Answer (score 0):

There are many better ways to do this. To follow a similar pattern to what you're looking for, here's one way of doing it:

```
public static class features
{
    public enum TYPES { favorite, nice }
    public static Dictionary<TYPES,string> values = new Dictionary<TYPES,string>() {
         { TYPES.favorite, "blue background" },
         { TYPES.nice, "animation" } };
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       foreach (string feature in features.values.keys)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(features.values[feature]);
       }
       //... select a feature
       Console.WriteLine(features.values[TYPES.favorite]);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So really what you are asking for is an object with Properties you can change and is also enumerable, but makes it so you don't need to call reflection to enumerate unless absolutely necessary.

If what I assume you are actually looking is the following

```
public class Features: IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> _internalCollection;

    public Features()
    {
        _internalCollection = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }

    private string GetByKey(string id)
    {
        if(!_internalCollection.ContainsKey(id))
            return null;
        return _internalCollection[id];
    }

    private void SetByKey(string id, string value) 
    {
        _internalCollection[id]=value;
    }

    const string _favoriteId = "favorite";
    public string Favorite
    {
         get { return GetByKey(_favoriteId); }
         set { return SetByKey(_favoriteId,value);}
    }

    const string _niceId = "nice";
    public string Nice
    {
         get { return GetByKey(_niceId);}
         set { return SetByKey(_niceId, value);} 
    }

    public string this[string index]
    {
            get { return GetByKey(index.ToLower()); }
            set { return SetByKey(index.ToLower(), value);}  
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach(var key in _internalCollection.Keys)
            yield return _internalCollection[key];
        yield break;
    }
}
```